# How to debug XLL Excel plugin with a release-built 3rd party library?

Tags: c++, excel, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, xll

I'm working on C++ code building an XLL Excel add-in, in order to be able to debug it using Visual Studio 2013, I compile with `/MTd` option, a.k.a. "Multi-thread, Debug mode" but hit such a compilation error:

`2>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl _invalid_parameter(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?_invalid_parameter@@YAXPBG00II@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)`

According to [Visual Studio - error LNK2005 in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885548/visual-studio-error-lnk2005-in-debug-mode) , it's because of linking against both `LIBCMT` (Microsoft Runtime Library, release version) and `LIBCMTD` (the debug version); the work-around is to add linker option `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` to force a build, and `/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT` to ignore `LIBCMT`.

However, after this my XLL can compile but couldn't be debugged, i.e. in Project Properties, Configuration Properties -> Debugging, I set Command to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.exe"`; after I launch Debugger, key-in a formula calling function from XLL, Visual Studio breakpoint should be triggered here but failed.

My XLL uses a 3rd party component, a database library. 
Is it that all the code to be compiled in `/MTd` mode, including the database library? Or I missed something, there actually is a way to trigger breakpoint in Visual Studio, even if the 3rd party library is not compiled in debug mode?

Comment: Did you try to temporary remove the dependency to your 3rd part library and to debug, to be sure that it is caused by it ?

Comment: or can you try to ignore the LIBCMT libray ? - Project + Properties, Linker, Input, Ignore Specific Library = LIBCMT.lib.

Comment: @athos, you could also visit the output windows or the modules windows, and check that whether it is related to the specific assembly loaded.